# how to get all the child category name in a specified category name?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query

Supposed the specified category name is "product", which has three layered sub-categories. The structure is like the following:

- product one

  - product two

    - product three

      - product four

I want to output all the subcategory names in the `sidebar.php` of my theme. How do I do?

in my theme index.php i using: `<?php include("productHallofHome.php");?>`
in productHallofHome.php i using code:

```
<ul class="productList_h">
<?php wp_list_categories( 'child_of=4&depth=0'); ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories), which is all you need. Just choose the arguments to your liking and place the code in your sidebar.

Suppose, the ID of your 'product' category is 666, then the basic code could look like the following:

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( 'child_of=666&hide_empty=0'); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: i am sorry, it not work.it shows no category.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the current code to it so we can see what you tried (and maybe why/where you failed).

Comment: it's ok now. but it only output the first layer category name. eg:the above is output product two. can't ouput product three
product fou

Comment: If you didn't include the argument `depth=1` it should be 0 by default (which means _all the way down_). Please edit the question and include your current code.

Comment: i put my code to my question, thank you. when i add depth=0, it is only  output the first layer category name

Comment: I guess, your other categories are empty...? Add `&hide_empty=0` to the arguments, if you want to list all (even empty) categories.

Comment: i am sorry, it is still not work. there are posts under the hidden category.

Comment: could you test it in your local environment. thank you.

Comment: I **did** test the code - works perfectly for me. Are you sure, you have the categories structured in the described hierarchical manner?

Comment: oh,damn it.there is a css using overflow:hidden. hide those category names. many thanks.

Comment: Ah, okay. Tricky thing that you found out. Glad I could be of some help.